# Interview offer, but I still need to submit 30 days notice

Tags: interviewing

I would like to ask on how to respond the email regarding an invitation for an initial interview. Actually, I am still employed and will send my resignation letter (with 30 days notice) if I am able to find a new job.

At this time, I am confused on how to respond to their email, and ask if they are willing to wait 30 days if they would hire me?

Comment: You should usually give notice after accepting the offer, not before the interview. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Just reply that you are open for an interview, discuss a mutually suitable time and go for it. Only once you get the job you need to give notice to your current employer. Most companies will ask you your notice period, and they will be happy to wait for you to complete it post they send you an offer letter.

Comment: Any normal company would expect (a minimum) of 30 days notice before you can start as normal.

Comment: Accept the interview, and discuss the notice period when the time comes, after you get an offer.

Comment: Having a notice period and asking when potential employees can start is standard. Wait until the topic comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you state that you are currently in an employment in your application, so the company inviting you will know you are not free to join "today".You should know when your earliest possible entry date will be, so if they ask you about this you don´t have to go back and look into your contract. Other than that, just go through with the interview and, if the want to hire you, your starting date is usually part of the negotiation of the terms of you employment.

Answer (score 2):

In many places in the world 30 days isn't an unusual amount of notice so I wouldn't worry - and you aren't at the point where you need to be giving notice yet (generally you do so after you have received a firm offer). It's pretty common to discuss what your notice period is at interview so it will probably come up then.